# Codeigniter setting multiple where conditions, how to unset one

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause

I've got a script that is a notify_url from paypal that is supposed to update multiple tables in my database using the following code:

//update first table
$this->db->where('someid', $somid);
$this->db->update('table', $data);

///update second table

$this->db->where('somesecondid', $somesecondid)
$this->db->update('anothertable', $data2);
Then I get the following error: Unknown column 'somesecondid' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `anothertable` SET `avail` = 0 WHERE `someid` = '13' AND `somesecondid` = '199'

So codeigniter is combining those where clauses into a single query. Is there a way to unset the first one so it only has "UPDATE anothertable SET avail=0 WHERE somesecondid = 199" ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into Active Record Caching in the user_guide...
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#caching
Maybe you have '$this->db->start_cache()' somewhere earlier in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I'm unable to replicate your error. I'm successfully running two update statements as you have them above.

As an alternative, you *can* pass the `WHERE` clause information directly to `$this->db->update()` using an array (per the [CodeIgniter Active Record documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update)) like this:

```
$this->db->update('table', $data, array('someid' => $someid));
$this->db->update('anothertable', $data2, array('somesecondid' => $somesecondid));
```